# multiply all values in all columns by the number of days that correspond to the month in date?

Tags: r

An example of my data is here

```
    dput(s2[2,])
 structure(list(date = structure(4049, class = "Date"), `A` = 7, 
`At` = 0.0001780556), row.names = 2L, class = "data.frame")
```

How can I multiply all values in all columns by the number of days that correspond to the month in date and multiply by 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `days_in_month` function from `lubridate` we could extract the days of the present month, in this case 28 and then use `across` for each column except `date` and multiple by `days_in_month(date)` and by 10:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-date, ~days_in_month(date)*.*10))
```

```
        date    A         At
2 1981-02-01 1960 0.04985557
```

In case you want to keep the original values:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-date, ~days_in_month(date)*.*10, .names = "calculated_{.col}"))
```

```
        date A           At calculated_A calculated_At
2 1981-02-01 7 0.0001780556         1960    0.04985557
```

Or as suggested by @mkpt_uk:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-date, list(mult = ~days_in_month(date)*.*10)))
```

```
        date A           At A_mult    At_mult
2 1981-02-01 7 0.0001780556   1960 0.04985557
```

Comment: If you wish to keep the original variables you will need to provide a suffix to the name for the new variables so the function becomes `list(mult = ~days_in_month(date)*.*10)`

Comment: @mkpt_uk Thanks. I even did not registered that this could be desired. I updated my code!